# Is it possible to access db tables directly in spring to verify state

Tags: spring, testing, h2

I'm quite new to Spring and want to make sure that I am using @JoinTable and @ManuToMany etc correctly.

So I was thinking to test to create and delete some entites from the database and verify that tables such as jointable contains correct data.

**My problem is that I don't know how to access this table to verify it's content.**

Example:

(Pseudo code)

```
class Access
   Long id
    @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(
           name = "account_role",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id",     referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   Set<Role> roles

class Role
     Long id
```

This should create table named "account_role" that maps the Roles which the Account has. When one account is removed, this table should also be altered. Is it possible to access this table directly (in a convenient way) to verify the content?

I'm using in memory H2 for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with JdbcTemplate.